# QGIS contour plugin exception struck?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, contour, bathymetry

I am trying to make a depth map of one of the lakes that I manage. I recorded my data using a lowrance depth finder. I have imported the data into QGIS and now have all the points that were recorded with depth and Lat. and Long. When I try to use the contour plugin I get an exception struck #### error. The error displays a number but when I delete that line from the attribute table the number changes. I keep deleting the number of the error that is returned but it seems like an endless loop.

What am I doing?

Data:
[image: Example of data]

Error:
[image: This is the error I am getting.]

I can go through and manually delete points and after deleting a certain amount I no longer get the exception struck error. But by the time I do this I have lost many points and the map will no longer be accurate.

Comment: The plugin works for me. Are you sure the depth field is numeric? Can you add a few sample data lines or a screenshot to your question?

Comment: Sure I will add a screenshot of the attribute table and the points.

Comment: The points should be in a shapefile; a CSV file might not work.

Comment: they were imported as a csv but then I saved it as a shapefile. I was able to delete alot of points and make it work but it was not accurate since I lost too many points.

Comment: http://i1220.photobucket.com/albums/dd458/chadw1987/untitled1.png

Comment: That screenshot is a bit small and doesn't show all of your data. Try to create a new column for depth using the fieldcalculator. Use the `toint(X)`conversion.

Comment: Sorry not real familiar with how to use the field calculator but I am trying. I do know that the depth field is already type integer.

Comment: Could be related to [this recent reported bug](https://github.com/ccrook/QGIS-Contour-Plugin/issues/7) about having too many points. About how many points do you start with and are left when it starts working? What version of QGIS are you using? While it wouldn't solve *this* problem, have you considered an alternate approach of interpolating the points to a raster and then creating contours from that?

Comment: I am unaware of an alternative method. Like I said I am very new to QGIS, I am still learning the ropes. I am running version 2.2.0. I have around 18000 points when I start, and between 500-600 when it starts to work.

Comment: Looks like it is that bug then. The alternative method, as Andre covered already in an answer, is a two step process (point > raster > contour) instead of just one (point > contour). I'm not finding a single great QGIS tutorial, but you could review [this one](http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/20-intermediate-quantum-gis-tutorials/51-inverse-distance-weighting-idw-interpolation-using-qgis.html) then [this one](http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/19-beginner-quantum-gis-tutorials/56-how-to-generate-contours-using-raster-data-in-quantum-gis-qgis.html) for more detailed info.

Comment: I should point out that IDW (shown in a tutorial I linked to) may not be the best interpolation method to use for elevation/bathymetry data. I'm just trying to get the concept across, and I'm not as familiar with what's available in QGIS as ArcGIS. You'll want to do further research depending on how accurate / precise you want your map to be.

Comment: Maybe the Processing toolbox has better interpolation methods? The links you gave do not work anymore.

Comment: @AndreJoost And that's why we don't like links as answers. :) It appears gistutor.com is currently down for some reason. It was working when I posted them and seems to be a fairly popular site. Perhaps it's just a temporary issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you are lost at the moment:

https://github.com/ccrook/QGIS-Contour-Plugin/issues/7

Feel free to add your case to the bug tracker.

In the meantime, try `Raster -> Interpolation`, and make contour lines from that with `Raster -> Extraction -> Contour`. Maybe the Processing toolbox has better interpolation methods.